# System::Device::Location::GeoCoordinate returns wrong Latitude and Longitude

Tags: c++, forms, visual-studio-2019

i have implemented the GeoCoordinate in my program for receiving the geographic coordinates, as shown below:

```
double lat, lon;
GeoCoordinate(lat, lon);

GeoCoordinate^ coord = gcnew GeoCoordinate(lat, lon);


lat = coord->Latitude;
lon = coord->Longitude;

geo->Text = "lat " + lat + " lon " + lon;
```

for some reason i get false results, while google maps show that my current location is lat 31... lon 34... the values that GeoCoordinate returns are lat 1... lon 6...

any suggestion how i can fix this error ?

Comment: I have tested the code, the value returned by GeoCoordinate is the same as that displayed by google maps. If you are using a VPN? If so, I suggest you should disconnect the VPN when you use Google Maps to get the latitude and longitude.

Comment: Thanks Jeaninez. no, I'm not using any sort of VPN. To verify the accuracy of my location lat and lon, i checked and compared them to the Google Earth, which, as mentioned...are not the same (to say at least)...any other ideas ? have you tried your code exactly as mine ? using double var ? i also debugged it and made a breakpoint to check the lat and lon values, before inserting them to text box, and the values are same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I figured out the problem...

please see below code:

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher^ watcher = gcnew GeoCoordinateWatcher();
watcher->TryStart(false, System::TimeSpan(System::TimeSpan::FromMilliseconds(1000)));
    
lat = watcher->Position->Location->Latitude;
lon = watcher->Position->Location->Longitude;
```

it seems that I nedded to use the `GeoCoordinateWatcher`.